# Rails 4 unpermitted parameters for Postgres type array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently performed a migration turning a `string` column into a Postgres array. The migration was as follows:

```
  def change
    change_column :projects, :layout_slug, "varchar[] USING (string_to_array(layout_slug, ','))"
  end
```

Now, I'm running into an issue with `Unpermitted parameters: layout_slug`. I've tried all of the accepted answers for the other StackOverflow questions and they're still not working for me. Here are all of the variations I've tried so far:

```
def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:image_slug, { layout_slug: [] }, :category, ..., :selection => [:inputs => Project::ALLOWED_INPUTS.keys])
end

def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:image_slug, { :layout_slug => [] }, :category, ..., :selection => [:inputs => Project::ALLOWED_INPUTS.keys])
end
```

I then tried removing the brackets around `:layout_slug => []` and I got an error:

```
SyntaxError (/.../app/controllers/api/v1/projects_controller.rb:62: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
... :layout_slug => [], :category, :subcategory, :version, :ema...
...                               ^
/.../app/controllers/api/v1/projects_controller.rb:62: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
/.../app/controllers/api/v1/projects_controller.rb:165: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end):

# THIS ONE THROWS A SYNTAX ERROR
def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:image_slug, :layout_slug => [], :category, :subcategory, :version, :email, :zip_code, :selection => [:inputs => Project::ALLOWED_INPUTS.keys])
end
```

So then I moved `layout_slug` to the end, and it went back to throwing the `Unpermitted parameters: layout_slug` error again.

```
# This throws the same Unpermitted parameters error as before
def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:image_slug, ..., :selection => [:inputs => Project::ALLOWED_INPUTS.keys], :layout_slug => [])
end
```

I've double- and triple-checked the spelling, and I've verified that the front-end is submitting an Array.

What am I missing?? Was there something wrong with my migration? Or is there something blatantly wrong with my permit method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested your sample code and it seems to be fine:

```
raw_parameters = { :image_slug => "some_slug", :category => "A", :layout_slug => ["a", "b"] }
parameters = ActionController::Parameters.new(raw_parameters)
parameters.permit(:image_slug, :category, :layout_slug => []) 
# {"image_slug"=>"some_slug", "category"=>"A", "layout_slug"=>["a", "b"]}
```

Check your params `:layout_slug` format, perhaps that's the case